# Conditional independence of autoregression model

Tags: regression, normal-distribution, covariance, autocorrelation, independence

Let $K =\text{diag}(\kappa_i)$ be a diagonal $N \times N$ matrix with $\kappa_i >0$ and $B$ a symmetric matrix such that $I-B$ is invertible and whose diagonal elements $b_{ii}$ are zero. Then a random field $X$ that is normally distributed with mean zero and covariance matrix $(I-B)^{-1}K$ is said to be a conditional autoregression model.

In such a conditional autoregression model, I want to show that $b_{ij}$ implies that $X_i$ and $X_j$ are conditionally independent given $(X_t)_{t \in T\setminus \{i,j\}}$, where $T$ is the finite index of the random field $X$. And I am wondering what the (unconditional) correlation is between $X_i$ and $X_j$?

So, say
\begin{align}
\Sigma = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\Sigma_{11} & \Sigma_{12}\\
\Sigma_{21} & \Sigma_{22}
\end{pmatrix}_{n\times n}
\end{align}
where $\Sigma_{11}$ is a $1 \times 1$ and $\Sigma_{22}$ is a symmetric $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ matrix. And
\begin{align}
I-B= 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -b_{ij}\\
-b_{ij} & [I-B]
\end{pmatrix}_{n\times n}
\end{align}
where $[I-B]$ is a symmetric $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ matrix.

It could be shown that if $b_{ij}=0$ that 
\begin{align}
(I-B)^{-1}= 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & [I-B]^{-1}
\end{pmatrix}_{n\times n},
\end{align}
is this correct? And how to conclude from here that $X_i$ and $X_j$ are conditionally independent given $(X_t)_{t \in T\setminus \{i,j\}}$?